# React DraftJS cursor auto jumps to beginning after typing in existing content and started typing backwards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm using DraftJS to edit text contents, but when I tried to edit any existing contents that I've retrieved from DB and loaded into the Editor, the cursor auto jumps to the beginning of the texts and I started typing from backwards.

I've imported the `Editor` into `Bulletin.js`, so I have to get the content by passing `getContent` into `Editor` and retrieve back the raw html by using `getContent` in the `handleEditorChange` function of the `Editor`.

I've found out that if I've removed the `getContent` function to pass back the raw HTML in `handleEditorChange`, the editor works normally, but then I won't be able to get the html content back to `Bulletin.js`.

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-ptolemy-8m2cr?file=/src/components/Bulletin/Bulletin.js) the codesandbox that I've created for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you set on every change a new `EditorState` here:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (htmlContent) {
    let convertedToHTML = decodeURIComponent(htmlContent);
    const blocksFromHtml = htmlToDraft(convertedToHTML);
    const { contentBlocks, entityMap } = blocksFromHtml;
    const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
      contentBlocks,
      entityMap
    );
    setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(contentState));
  }
}, [htmlContent]);
```

`htmlContent` is always changing as you convert the `EditorState` to HTML on every change via the `getContent` function.

If you want to initialize your `EditorState` with the `htmlContent` you can do it in the `useState` function and remove the `useEffect`:

```js
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() => {
  if (htmlContent) {
    let convertedToHTML = decodeURIComponent(htmlContent);
    const blocksFromHtml = htmlToDraft(convertedToHTML);
    const { contentBlocks, entityMap } = blocksFromHtml;
    const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
      contentBlocks,
      entityMap
    );
    return EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
  }
  return EditorState.createEmpty()
});
```

Comment: How should I change the the way getContent works so that it won't convert the ```EditorState``` to HTML on every change? Not quite sure if I understood it correctly.

Comment: The `getContent` method is not the problem, the `setEditorState` in the `useEffect` is it. Just do it once at the creation of the component and not on every change

Comment: If I get this correctly, I just have to remove the ```[htmlContent]``` dependency from the useEffect right?

Comment: I have edited my answer and hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I see what you meant now, thanks. I've tried your method and implemented it in the codesandbox that I've provided, but now the editor doesn't load with the html content that I'm passing to it ```(<p>Hello world</p>)``` for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I found out that the reason the editor doesn't load with the html content that I passed to it is only because the html content haven't been loaded in time. Your method is definitely correct!